# raw data image is not displayed in picture control using StretchDIBits

Tags: mfc

I made a picture control (ID= IDC_PICTURE) to display raw data using StretchDIBits().

```
    HWND hDlg,hWndCtl;
    hWndCtl =::GetDlgItem(hDlg,IDC_PICTURE);
    hdc =:: GetDC(hWndCtl);
    ::StretchDIBits(hdc,0,0,width,height,0,0,width,height,raw_image,m_pBitMapInfo,DIB_RGB_COLORS,SRCCOPY);
```

But images is displayed on my desktop screen not inside picture control I made. How can I solve this problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

In the following line ...

```
hWndCtl =::GetDlgItem(hDlg,IDC_PICTURE);
```

... you haven't initialised `hDlg`, so it is probably failing and `hWndCtl` is being returned as `NULL`.

Then this line ...

```
 hdc =:: GetDC(hWndCtl);
```

... is effectively `GetDC(NULL)` which gives you the DC of the desktop.

So, to fix the problem, make sure you pass the `HWND` of your dialog to `GetDlgItem` or, as you are using MFC, use the `CWnd` version of `GetDlgItem` from within your `CDialog` derived class like this:

```
CWnd *pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_PICTURE);    // add error checking here for NULL return
HDC hdc =::GetDC(pWnd->GetSafeHwnd());   // use the HWND of the control to get the DC

// ... do the blit ...
```